# I'm unsure of how to solve this anonymous function closure question from my textbook

Tags: javascript, function, closures

The question is this:

*"One of your colleagues has written the following code routine, but it isn’t working the way she expected. Can you explain why? How would you fix the code so that it gives the output your colleague was expecting?"*

```
var output = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  output[i] = function () {
    console.log(i);
  }
}

output[0](); // logs 5, not the expected 0
output[1](); // logs 5, not the expected 1
output[2](); // logs 5, not the expected 2
output[3](); // logs 5, not the expected 3
output[4](); // logs 5, not the expected 4
```

Going through this chapter I had discovered a mistake in a previous example that was easy enough to pick up on. So analyzing the exercise worries me.

I understand closures are functions that can access parent variables. Rather than solving this for me, I wanted to know if the community point me in the right direction to solving this.

I have done research on this topic and I've completed 2 other tutorials on closures, I just don't understand this question. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of a variable declared with `var` is its current execution context, which is either the enclosing function or, for variables declared outside any function, global. `->` [Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Description)

So, basically, every execution will use the last assigned value to `i`.

*You have two options*

#### 1. [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```js
var output = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  output[i] = (function(i) {
    return function() {
      console.log(i);
    }
  })(i);
}

output[0](); // logs 5, not the expected 0
output[1](); // logs 5, not the expected 1
output[2](); // logs 5, not the expected 2
output[3](); // logs 5, not the expected 3
output[4](); // logs 5, not the expected 4
```

#### 2. [Statement `let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

> The `let` statement declares a *block scope local variable*, optionally initializing it to a value.

```js
var output = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  output[i] = function() {
    console.log(i);
  }
}

output[0](); // logs 5, not the expected 0
output[1](); // logs 5, not the expected 1
output[2](); // logs 5, not the expected 2
output[3](); // logs 5, not the expected 3
output[4](); // logs 5, not the expected 4
```